# Create a view that changes a ',' character into a ':' in one field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I was wondering if its possible to create a view that when pulling in one column of data that contains a comma delimited field in the table but when pulled into a view makes the field semi colon delimited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure:

```
create view vwYourView as
select col1, col2, replace(col3, ',', ';') as col3
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`REPLACE()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) in your view definition:

```
SELECT col1, col2, REPLACE(col3, ',' ':') AS col3 FROM table
```

This does not, however, account for CSV data that may be quote-enclosed, comma-delimited, and possibly include commas inside the quotes.